How to auto refresh excel dashboard on file/data modification
I have created a power query in excel which will refresh every 1 hr. But Is it possible to set the refresh properties to refresh the data on data change in the source file ? Thanks in advance.

Excel does not have a built-in feature to automatically refresh Power Query connections directly based on changes in the source file so you can use VBA like in the following example based on the modification date of the file (but keep in mind you can have a new version of your file but with the same data) :
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "CheckForChanges"
End Sub

Sub CheckForChanges()
    Dim lastModifiedTime As Date
    Dim sourceFilePath As String
    
    sourceFilePath = "C:\path\to\your\sourcefile.xlsx"
    
    lastModifiedTime = FileDateTime(sourceFilePath)
    
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value <> lastModifiedTime Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = lastModifiedTime
        
        ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    End If

    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "CheckForChanges"
End Sub

https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Query/VBA-Code-to-Refresh-Power-Query/td-p/2449582
If you're using Office 365 you can create a new flow with Power Automate to trigger a refresh when the source file changes.
https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Query/VBA-Code-to-Refresh-Power-Query/td-p/2449582
If you are looking for incremental refresh : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cxOH9qsDunA

Thank you so much. Will try this. For the below statement- (but keep in mind you can have a new version of your file but with the same data) : Yep Noted.                                For the Power Automate part - I did have a look into this but Power Automate is not freely available right? Have not used it before. Need to buy subscription I think. Not sure though. Pls confirm if you are aware. Thanks in advance.

The free version of Power Automate Desktop is suitable for individual automation tasks but lacks some collaborative and advanced features available in paid plans.
Don't forget to validate my answer if it helped you :)
